# Two tier expand and collapse in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a task in which I need to implement two tier or two level expand-collapse functionality. For example if I clicking on a cell say C1, one more cell will be displayed say C2 and again if I click on C2, one more cell say C3 will be visible. Here clicking again on these cell will hide them respectively. I searched on google for this but didn't get anything so if you guys have any solution for this please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this github repository](https://github.com/Augustyniak/RATreeView). I've used it in the past, and it has the potential to do exactly what you seem to want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks Matthew Hallatt!!!

Comment: How I will get indexpath of any cell as this repository doesn't using delegate methods of uitableview.